# Once your updated app is uploaded to the Developer Console, how long will it take for users be notified

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, playframework

I am trying to understand between the system Pre-load vs Stub app experience. I am planning to load an my app as stub application and pre-loaded on system partition. I will push an update in the future. My question here is that after I post an update on google play Developer Console,

1. how long will it take for users be notified and
2. is there anyway that i can force an update since this application is in system partition.

Thanks in advance

Droigon

Answer (score 0):

1.. For me it usually took anything from 24h to 3,4 days for a notification to show in users phones.

---Sometimes it wouldnt show as a single notification, rather it would pop on a regular check for updates that the google play services app does by it self, when all apps that have updates show up in noifications.

2.. You cant push the notification officially through google play. But you can push the notification using other means when you update your app. (GCM for ex.) . But still this doesnt mean the user will update the app. You cant force them to update, only offer it to them. You arent also forced to do software updates for your phone ;)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there are no fixed times, just as there are no fixed rules.

It seems to be a bit random, maybe simply dependent on a max amount of apps they can run a virusscan on at the same time.

How long it takes before the user gets a notification about this, or gets an automatic update is completely up to the user (settings, internet connection, some people just ignore updates..).

So basically;
1. You can't know. It is different for every user since there are settings and requirements for this which are personal.
2. No.

Maybe it's better to focus on **why** you can't just offer it as 1 update